# Associations two-many-to-many

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I don't fully understand how associations work.

I have 3 models:

1. **Movie** (:about, :title, :url, :actors, :uploader)
2. **Actor** (:birth, :name)
3. **Relationships** (:actor_id, :film_id)

Relationships is the association between Movies and Actors, so "which actor play in which movie". My teacher told me I can make it easier with http://railscasts.com/episodes/47-two-many-to-many but I don't know how to use that, any idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would imagine you want something like:

```
class Movie < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :actors, :through => :relationships
end

class Relationship < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :movie
  belongs_to :actor
end

class Actor < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :movies, :through => :relationships
end
```

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has_many-through-association

Or alternatively, if you don't feel you  have to define the relationship class explicitly, you can simply use `has_and_belongs_to_many`:

```
class Movie < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :actors
end

class Actor < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :movies
end
```

Comment: the second approach would be better since he is not storing any additional info for the intermediate table. check the guides: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has_and_belongs_to_many-association

Comment: True, however some dislike rail's implementation of join tables.

Comment: Well ok, maybe for a beginner the first one is better, but the second one is more correct.

Comment: Ty, and if I create a new relationship between 3 actors and 1 movie, how can i call it?

Comment: `m = Movie.find_by_name "Jaws"; m.actors`

Comment: and its make 3 relationship record?
so if i have 1 movie with id: 12 
m = Movie.find(12);
m.actors
??
I dont understand what its make

Comment: it will return an array of the Actor objects associated with the Movie. If you want to add to that array you can do `m.actors << Actor.find(1)`

Comment: No, `m` is the Movie. `m.actors` is essentially the array of actors associated with that movie.

Comment: Movie.find(x).actors << Actor.find(y) ?
I have checkboxes with the actors id, so if i make it for an array **a =[32,12,43]**
the code looks  like = m.actors << a ?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/27480/discussion-between-mike-campbell-and-ben-c-taylor)